# jquery function call on page both onload and onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am working on jquery calender but i need to call a function both on page load and then on click. when the page load for the first time it should automatically call and execute the function and for 2nd time and onward it should be call through click. is it possible?? if yes please help me.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#fullDate").datepicker({

        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calender.jpg",
        buttonImageOnly: true,

        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        $('#year').val(dateText.split('/')[2]);
        $('#month').val(dateText.split('/')[0]);
        $('#day').val(dateText.split('/')[1]);
    }


    });


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#fullDate").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calender.jpg",
    buttonImageOnly: true,

    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        $('#year').val(dateText.split('/')[2]);
        $('#month').val(dateText.split('/')[0]);
        $('#day').val(dateText.split('/')[1]);
    }
  });
  $("#fullDate").datepicker("show"); // this will run once.
});
```

Comment: its working fine but still there is something missing. when page loads a calender pop out automatically which is superb but it should disappear as well automatically. but the the poping out and then disappearing of calender should be very fast that a user cannot see the calender on page load. user can only see the calender on click only but 1st the function should be call its self execute the function. in short all the process that happens on a click from very start to the final end should be done for the first time automatically without click. thanx

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to show/hide a calendar picker without the user being able to see it -- I can't think of any benefits. But just use `$("#fullDate").datepicker("hide");` straight after the `show`. Funny how my answer is the only one that answers the (inferred) question, yet gets no upvotes.

Comment: i will explain why i need this once i get my desired functionality.

did u meand like that aahren??  $("#fullDate").datepicker("show").$("#fullDate").datepicker("hide");

if yes its not working i dont know why??

Comment: make them two separate lines. `$("#fullDate").datepicker("show");` and `$("#fullDate).datepicker("hide");`. It's better to explain why you 'need' something before someone gives you an answer, because they may have better ideas about how to get the job done, without having to take that specific route.

Comment: yes you are right sorry if you guys felt troubled caz of me. but for next time i will be carefull. by the way its got worked. thanks alot ahren and all others that tried to help me.thumb up

Comment: dear ahren the reason was that i had one hidden text field which have a hardcoded value(date), and there are three separate drop down for day month and year. wat i need was that for first time when page loads the function should execute and the date in hidden field should split in its parts i.e day month and year and display in there respective drop down. that's why i need to hide a calander from a user for the first time. hope u get my point.

Answer (score 5):

Try writing a named function and call it on both events:

```
function doSomething() {
    // ...
}
$(document).ready(function() { doSomething() });
$(yourElem).on("click", function() { doSomething() });
```

Alternatively to writing an anonymous function as a callback, just to call `doSomething`, you could also pass the function name as an argument, gaining a little performance by not cluttering memory with unnecessary anonymous functions:

```
$(document).ready(doSomething);
$(yourElem).on("click", doSomething);
```

Comment: Better use the new .on() method.

Comment: no need to wrap a function call inside a callback. just use `$(document).ready(doSomething);`

Comment: @ahren In this case this was indeed better, I'll add it. But how about passing arguments? Might be possible, too, but I don't know how. Maybe you can tell me?

Answer (score 1):

During load, you can use

```
//when window loads
$(window).load(function(){
    functionCallHere();
});

//or when DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function(){
    functionCallHere();
});
```

Then for the click

```
$(element).click(function(){
    functionCallHere();  //call the function again
});
```

Where `functionCallHere` is the name of the common function called on those events.